# Very strange behavior - printf & strcmp ignore my input string in only one line

Tags: c, unix

this is the code:

```
printf("   DEBUG:%s\n" ,array[7] );
printf("address of %s is %p  (again %d)\n",
    array[7],
    array[7],
    strcmp("N\\A", array[7]) );

printf("5DEBUG collection:%s\n" ,array[7] );
```

this is the output:

DEBUG:N\A

is 0x7c0600  (again -13)

5DEBUG collection:N\A

as you can see , in the second printf - array[7] (need to point to "N\A" ) disappeared.

I have no idea whats going on here...

Comment: What is the contents of `array` ?

Comment: just array of strings (array of char*).  btw in windows it works well

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are reading a Windows-formatted file on unix. Windows and unix use different line terminators. Unix uses 0x0A, whereas Windows use 0x0D followed by 0x0A.

If you have a line in the file that ends in 0x0D 0x0A, unix will treat the 0x00A as the line terminator but include the 0x0D as part of the string.

You can see this in your `strcmp`, which returns `-13`. Notice that it does not return zero, which means that the strings are not equal. In fact, the difference is 13, the decimal value of 0x0D, which confirms that `array[7]` has a 0x0D at the end.

The other evidence of this is the odd printing behavior you're seeing. On unix, printing 0x0D causes the cursor to return to column 0 of the same line. Therefore, the second print instruction begins by printing

```
address of N\A
```

and then it encounters the 0x0D, which moves the cursor back to column 0. The remainder of the string therefore overprints the output, resulting in

```
 is 0x7c0600 (again -13)
```

If you tried to debug the program in a debugger with a breakpoint on the code, you would have noticed that `array[7]` has a `0x0D` at the end.

**Added**

This was not psychic debugging. It was actually quite straightforward. Here's the step-by-step:

1. When you noticed the odd behavior, you should use the debugger to look at the string in `array[7]`. If you had done that, you would have seen the trailing 0x0Dand the problem would have been solved in 5 seconds.
2. The next huge clue was that the result of `strcmp` was not zero. This means that the string in `array[7]` is not equal to `"N\\A"`, which is your next huge clue that you should use the debugger to look at the string in `array[7]` to see what it actually is.
3. Without the benefit of debugging, I observed that the difference between `array[7]` and `"N\\A"` must be in something that is not readily visible, since the first line printed okay. The options here are control characters or whitespace.
4. The fact that `strcmp` reported a difference of `13` suggests that the string in `array[7]` has an 0x0D at the end: `"N\\A"` ends with a `\0` (numerical value zero), and a difference of 13 suggests that `array[7]` ends with 0x0D, since 0x0d hex = 13 decimal.
5. If you didn't use the logic from step 4, you could have stopped to think, "What characters would mess up printing?" You run down the mental list. Space, tab (causes multiple spaces to be printed), carriage return (returns cursor to column 0), newline (advances to next line), form feed (clears the screen), and escape (introduces console control sequences). The one that matches the evidence is carriage return, whose ASCII code is (surprise) 13.
6. If you didn't use the logic from steps 4 or 5, you could have studied the statement that the problem does not exist on Windows. Windows uses 0x0D 0x0A as its line terminator, whereas unix uses 0x0A. The extra 0x0D is a carriage return which returns the cursor to column 0, which again matches the evidence.

So there were four independent ways of coming to the same diagnosis. (Five if you count "Look at the string in the debugger.") Since they all agreed, this made for a rather confident conclusion. My actual analysis started with step 5, then used the other steps to confirm the diagnosis.

Comment: Raymond, your semi-psychic debugging skills are **AWESOMER** than your psychic debugging skills!

Comment: @NikBougalis This was hardly psychic. I added an explanation.

Comment: That's why I said "semi-psychic" ;) But still good to see the thought-process behind it.